# trouble connecting with thingspeak

Tags: python

I am having trouble connecting a simple temp, humidity, dew point logger to Thingspeak, this code was working (I thought it was anyway) put this project down for a couple of weeks now having problems.

when I run it I get the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "DHH-test5.py", line 14, in <module>
conn.request("POST", "/update", params,)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1001, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1035, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 997, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 850, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 812, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 793, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

My code is as follows

```
 import sys
 import Adafruit_DHT
 import time
 import httplib, urllib

 for x in range(0,500):
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)
    if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
       DP= temperature-(100-humidity)/5
       print x,'minutes---Temp={0:0.1f} deg C  Humidity={1:0.1f}% Dewpoint={2:0.2f} deg c'.format(temperature,humidity,DP)
       print '  '
       params = urllib.urlencode({'field1':temperature, 'field2': humidity, 'field3':DP,'key': 'app key here'})
       conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.thingspeak.com:80")
       conn.request("POST", "/update", params,)
       response = conn.getresponse()
       print response.status, response.reason
       data = response.read()
       conn.close()
       time.sleep(20)
    else:
       print 'Failed to get reading. Try again!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, for some reason my wifi connection was connected but couldn't get internet access, reinstalled raspbian and tried again and works